# Overriding backbutton android phonegap 1.8 jqmobile 1.1.0 jquery 1.7.1

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, back-button

I recently started developing a mobile app in Phonegap 1.8 + Jquerymobile 1.1.0 +jquery 1.7.1 for Android 2.3.3. My problem is: 
I've tried overriding backbutton in Android in several ways, nothing works though. I've tried using

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", handleBackButton, false);
function handleBackButton() {//do sth}
```

then I've just overrided it in Application.java code. And it works... almost.
My 1st page (index.html) is being just used to login after that there is main page (main.html) with links to other pages. I've overrided backbutton to goback on every other page than login and main. On those two pages it should exit the app after clicking "yes" in AlertDialog. Well, in MainPage it shows the AlertDialog and then goes straight back to login page without waiting even for my response. On login page it just shows the AlertDialog and waits for my reaction. Don't know why. Here is some of my code.

```
public void onBackPressed() {

  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
  .setCancelable(false)
  .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             SampleApplication.this.finish();
         }
     })
     .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
              dialog.cancel();
         }
     });
  AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
  String testUrl = appView.getUrl();      

  if(testUrl.equals("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"))
  {
      alert.show();
  }
  if (testUrl.equals("file:///android_asset/www/main.html"))
  {
      alert.show();
  }
  if ((!testUrl.equals("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")) && (!testUrl.equals("file:///android_asset/www/main.html")))
  { 
      this.appView.goBack();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use the regular back button on all pages that you want the regular back button behaviour but create a separate button for the pages where you need a different behaviour and just make it look like the normal back button:

In your header bar, just add an anchor where you add a custom data-rel (and hook it up to whatever function you want) e.g.

```
<a data-rel="custombackbtn">Back</a>
```

Then add in that data-rel to wherever your regular back button is styled (your theme's css or regular css) so, wherever there's a mention of a[data-rel='back'] add data-rel='custombackbtn' e.g.

```
a[data-rel='back'], .ui-header a[data-rel='back'] {
*/Styling*/
}
```

is changed to

```
a[data-rel='back'], .ui-header a[data-rel='back'], a[data-rel='backbtn'], .ui-header a[data-rel='backbtn'] {
*/Styling*/
}
```

Comment: Thx Hessius, but I've managed to get it work with default phonegap backbutton override. There was a problem with android's manifest.xml file. In order to get the backbutton override work u have to change minsdk ver to 2 and targetsdk to at least 14, then the addListener on backbutton will work just fine.